# Need to run job on direct change or push but not on merge

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow with two jobs, *tests* and *build*. *tests* job I want to run when any branch gets pushed into but it should not get run when I do merge from any branch to another. Aim is to prevent long running *tests* job during merge because it already gets executed when we push code.

```yaml
name: PR test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
    tags-ignore:
      - '**'

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          echo "tests run"

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build 
        run: |
          echo "Build"
```

[image]

When I add `if` condition under job *tests*:

```
github.ref != 'refs/heads/develop' && github.event.pull_request.merged == false
```

...it helps to run *tests* job when I push in any branch and prevents *tests* job when I merge into *develop* but it also prevents when I do direct change and push in *develop* branch while I want it to run on direct push.

Note: Answer should be with native github workflow job definition condition, it should not be under steps. Also answer shouldn't based on commiter name. You can use this repo for testing if you wish https://github.com/hk1313/prtest

Comment: *...but it should not get run when do merge from any one branch to another* - if it's for any branch, why would you have `github.ref != 'refs/heads/develop'` as part of the condition?

Comment: @tmt, I have branch test1. I added condition on test job   "github.event.pull_request.merged == false"  When I push code on test1, it run test job as I needed but when I merge with develop branch, it still run test job but it should not. Still I did not check with direct push on develop branch.

Comment: The problem is that there is no difference for GittHub if a commit was created by direct push or after merge.

Comment: Will merges only happen through pull requests, or does this also need to work if e.g. a developer merges a branch into develop locally and then pushes the merge?

Comment: @goric, it's pull request and merge, not local merge.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to add an if statement that would check if it's a push or not, for example:

```
name: PR test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
    tags-ignore:
      - '**'

jobs:
  tests:
    if: |
      !(github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true)

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          echo "tests run"

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build 
        run: |
          echo "Build"
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Do you have a working repo?

Comment: Will test and back to you.

Comment: @B''H Bi'ezras -- Boruch Hashem

I don't know how stackoverflow transfer bounty credit. I checked your answer and it not worked.  you can see in repo https://github.com/hk1313/prtest.